# React navigation custom header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

Im trying to use react-navigation custom header like this

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: <EventHeader
        subscribestatus={this.props.navigation.getParam('status')}
        confirmation={this.props.navigation.getParam('confirmation')}
        deleteSubscribe={this.deleteSubscribe}
        joinEvent={this.joinEvent}
        onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.goBack()}
        eventname={this.props.navigation.getParam('title')}
    />
};
```

This header getting params previous screen as you see but im getting
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')

What i am doing wrong and how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you found the solution, but for other people which could come here  :

`navigationOptions` can be a `function` which will pass `navigator` as first argument and can return an object.
So you could write it like so :

`static navigationOptions = (navigator) => {
  return {
    header: (
      <EventHeader
        subscribestatus={navigator.navigation.getParam('status')}
        confirmation={navigator.navigation.getParam('confirmation')}
        //deleteSubscribe={this.deleteSubscribe}
        //joinEvent={this.joinEvent}
        onPress={()=>navigator.navigation.goBack()}
        eventname={navigator.navigation.getParam('title')}
      />
    )
  }
}`

Unfortunately, you will not have access to this.deleteSubscribe or this.joinEvent